# Grails Unit test Controller GSON

Tags: grails, gson

I'm trying to write a unit test for a simple controller that takes GSON as input and writes to DB. 
GSON because, the input has nested objects.

Unit testing works if i use JSON, but JSON has its limitations with nested objects.

Domain Class:

```
class Artist { 
    String guid 
    String name 

    static constraints = { 
        name nullable: true 
    }

    static mapping = { 
        guid blank:false, unique: true 
    }

    static hasMany = [albums: Albums] 
    /*static marshalling={ deep 'albums' }*/ 
}
```

Controller implementation:

```
def create() {
    def artist = new Artist(request.GSON)
    if (!artist.save(flush: true)) {
        artist.errors.each {
        log.error("Error while creating Artist " + it)
        }
        render status: 500, layout: null
        return
    }
    response.status = 201
    render artist as GSON
}
```

Unit test:

```
@TestMixin(GsonUnitTestMixin)
@TestFor(ArtistController)
@Mock(Artist)
class ArtistControllerTests {
    void testCreate() {
        request.GSON = "{guid:123,"+
                                       "name: 'Akon',"+
                "albums: ["+
                "{guid:1,"+
                "name:'album 1'"+
                "}]}"
        controller.create()
        assert response.status == 201
       }
   }
```

Exception:
Cannot get property 'manyToOne' on null object at
def artist = new Artist(request.GSON) in the controller

Any help will be greatly appreciated..

Comment: How does `Artist` domain class look like?

Comment: Artist domain:`class Artist { String guid String name static constraints = { name nullable: true } static mapping = { guid blank:false, unique: true } static hasMany = [albums: Albums] /* static marshalling={ deep 'albums' }*/ } `